# Java painting mechanism on OverlayLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d

Is there a way to create a layered system of components in Java so that at one moment only one layer will be updated (repainted)?

The simplest example would be a large map, with thousands of shapes and labels that will be placed on a "bottom" layer. And on the "top" layer you have another small shape, a custom tooltip would be a good example for this scenario. Now, whenever the tooltip's position is getting updated (by mouse move), even if you specifically call repaint() on that component only, the whole frame is being updated (thus a repaint is called on each layer, making the whole system pretty slow and ineffective).

I know you can achieve some optimization by caching contents as images and paint images instead of thousands of shapes, but, still, I'm interested in a "simpler" solution.

Thank you.

Sample code:

Basically there is a main frame (m) which loads a container (mc) and this container has two "layers" (ml). Now, when I call repaint() just for the 2nd layer, it's easy to see all paintComponent() are called again (console text appears but also BOTH rectangles change color to a new random one). And that is what I need to prevent.

**File: m.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
 
public class m extends JFrame {
 
    public mc omc;
 
    public m() {
        initUI();
    }
 
    private void initUI() {
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(600, 680);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
 
        this.omc = new mc();
        this.add(omc);
 
        m self = this;
        Timer oTimer = new Timer();
        oTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                self.omc.oml1.repaint();
            }
        }, 2000);
 
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                m ex = new m();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**File: mc.java**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
 
public class mc extends JPanel {
 
    public ml oml0;
    public ml oml1;
 
    public mc() {
        this.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(this));
        this.oml0 = new ml(0);
        this.oml1 = new ml(1);
 
        this.add(oml0);
        this.add(oml1);
    }
 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("mc");
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
 
}
```

**File: ml.java**

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 
public class ml extends JPanel {
 
    private int l = 0;
 
    public ml(int ll) {
        this.l = ll;
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }
 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("ml:" + this.l);
        super.paintComponent(g);
 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
 
        if (this.l == 0) {
            g2d.setPaint(new Color((int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random()), (int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random()), (int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random())));
            g2d.fillRect(30, 30, 300, 100);
        }
        if (this.l == 1) {
            g2d.setPaint(new Color((int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random()), (int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random()), (int)Math.round(100 + 150 * Math.random())));
            g2d.fillRect(130, 80, 300, 100);
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Swing only repaints the area that is necessary. If you invoke repaint() on a panel, the entire panel is repainted. If you invoke repaint on a component on the panel, then only the component is repainted. However, if you invoke repaint() on two components one the panel, then the area between the two components is repainted.

Comment: Post a proper [mre] in the forum (not on pastebin).

Comment: Your components are transparent. When you invoke repaint() on a transparent panel, Swing looks for a parent component that is not transparent. The component is painted to make sure the background is painted completely. Then the child components are painted. Don't try to use an OverlayLayout. This will not work. If you make the components opaque, then you will only see the top component.

Comment: If you need to paint in layers then yes you also need to repaint the layer below. For example if you have a component on the top layer in the top/left and you move that component to the bottom/right, then the layer below also needs to be painted so you can now see what is displayed in the top/right. Generally people to all the painting in a single class. Maybe paint a background image, then on top of the image you paint other objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I understand this is "the way" Java is doing it, but isn't that really ineffective if, for example, you have 5000 shapes on a bottom layer and just one one the top layer and you only need to move the one from the top? Without a caching mechanism you're really screwed. Anyways, thank you again.

Comment: *nd just one one the top layer* - Do you move the object a few pixels, or do you move the object from the top/left to bottom/right? When you specify repaint() you can use repaint(bounds). Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html). The example shows how you might be provide a "clipped" area for the painting. The code tracks the current location of the square and the new location. Only the area between to two are repainted. So if you have incremental movement, this will reduce the clipped area that needs to be painted..